# Country state/city dropdown in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any readily available snippet that has all the countries, states and cities for showing in a drop down in html for selection?

What is standard for this? Does everyone roll their own?

The snippet can be in html, javascript, jquery plugin.

NOTE: I know how to make chained dropdown. I'm more concerned with the data rather than technique.

Comment: @tjameson: you are asking him to steal it ? its not a good habit .

Comment: @tjameson And take all of their mistakes or self-imposed limitations. Very good idea. @Hasan, do you mean all the countries in the entire world *and* all their subdivisions? Or does 'states and cities' only refer to those in a subset of countries?

Comment: @D_N- It's just a drop down list... there really aren't limitations there. @Hameed- It's not like a list of countries, states, and cities is proprietary in any way, it's publicly available data.

Comment: @D_N I meant all the countries in the entire world.

Comment: @tjameson With this sort of scope, it's not just a drop down.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529129/open-source-country-region-selector-in-js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the data for free - Good luck getting 33MB presented in a drop down ;)

Seems they also have a [JavaScript API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/javascript_city) - (found via [Best way to get user nearest city? Python/Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512329/best-way-to-get-user-nearest-city-python-django)) to start you off with the user's (IP) location

In the foreseeable future there may be a JSON interface according to Peter Saczkowski
Operations Manager | Maxmind, Inc.:

> Yes, we are actually considering switching over to JSON, but don't
>   have a timeline quite on when that will happen.  If/when this happens,
>   we'll have updates in our newsletter and on the site.

**Disclaimer** I'm not affiliated with MaxMind and the themselves suggest to also look at [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/)

---

### [MaxMind World Cities with Population](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities)   Last Updated: May 17th, 2011

> Product Summary: Includes city, region, country, latitude and
>   longitude. This product doesn't contain any IP addresses. It's simply
>   a listing of all the cities in the world. For IP to city mappings, see
>   our MaxMind City product.
>
> Note that this product is now a free download [33 MB]. The database
>   will be updated about once per year, since the city data doesn't
>   change that frequently. [license]
>
> The database uses toponymic information, based on the Geographic Names
>   Data Base, containing official standard names approved by the United
>   States Board on Geographic Names and maintained by the National
>   Geospatial-Intelligence Agency. More information is available at the
>   Maps and Geodata link at www.nga.mil. The National
>   Geospatial-Intelligence Agency name, initials, and seal are protected
>   by 10 United States Code Section 445.
>
> It also uses free population data © by Stefan Helders
>   www.world-gazetteer.com. Visit his website to download the free
>   population data. Our database combines Stefan's population data with
>   the list of all cities in the world.
>
> Another free cities database is available from GeoNames.

### Product Features - MaxMind World Cities with Population

```
Includes the following fields:
    Country Code
    ASCII City Name
    City Name
    State/Region
    Population
    Latitude
    Longitude
    Timezone data is available through an external lookup
Approximately 2,710,000 records. 

Database Fields
Field               Data Type       Field Description
Country Code        char(2)         ISO 3166 Country Code,
ASCII City Name     varchar(100)    Name of city or town in ASCII encoding
City Name           varchar(255)    Name of city or town in ISO-8859-1 encoding. A list of cities contained in GeoIP City is available.
State/Region        char(2)         For US, ISO-3166-2 code for the state/province name. Outside of the US, FIPS 10-4 code
Population          unsigned int    Population of city (available for over 33,000 major cities only)
Latitude            numeric (float) Latitude of city where IP is located
Longitude           numeric (float) Longitude of city where IP is located
```

Comment: So it appears the data is so huge that it can't fit in a single javascript / html snippet and there is apparently no web service for this. Yahoo's Geo something service is useless, I tried it.

Comment: Outdated content, the links are broken.

Comment: 10 years later surprise surprise ;)

Comment: https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city Updated last week

Answer (score 8):

Any code containing all that data would be a lot more than a snippet. I don't think you'll find a standard component for this, and I wouldn't trust any I found that claim to. There's too much subjectivity along with making your own judgements about how comprehensive you want to be.

- This sort of data [changes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Sudan) [constantly](http://www.startribune.com/local/124328119.html) and in many cases [isn't universally agreed upon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes). I see you're from Pakistan; under which country should Kashmir be listed? See also: [Burma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burma) (or do I mean Myanmar?)
- Not everything fits neatly into city/state/country classes. Should Puerto Rico be listed as a country or a US state? Then you've got Crown Dependencies, Outlying Territories, Protectorates, Self-governing Colonies, [etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aDependent_territories).
- Compiling a complete list of states (more generally [Subnational entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_division), to include territories, districts, provinces, prefectures and lots more) and especially **cities** (do you really want to include Lost Springs, Wyoming, population :1?) would be quite an accomplishment. I'm not sure even the [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/index.html) is that comprehensive.

Some other good sources when rolling your own are

- [ISO Country Codes](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html)
- [ISO state codes](http://www.commondatahub.com/static/geography/state_province_region/iso_3166_2_state_codes.0000000001.html)

Comment: you're right about it being subjective but honestly speaking I'm more concerned with allowing the user to specify the territory that he belongs to. It doesn't matter if the owning country or continent is a disputed issue. If a user can't find Kashmir in Pakistan, he'll look for it in India because his end goal is selecting Kashmir be it anywhere.

Comment: Even if you're not particular about the placement, the troop buildup on the border indicates that some people take it *very* seriously, as is the case with all the other disputed territories. Are you ok with taking sides and putting off those people, and which side do you take? The larger point is that because the data isn't agreed upon and in some cases is simply ill-defined, no standard is possible.

Comment: It also occurs to me that using freeform text fields for this and using your country/state/city database to offer spelling corrections is probably a sounder approach.

Answer (score 3):

i too got into this same problem and here is some links that helped.

http://www.javascriptsource.com/forms/country-state-drop-down.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/countries/files/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```html
<html>
<head> 
<title>Demo by kishan Radadiya</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Countries
        var country_arr = new Array("Select Country","AUSTRALIA","INDIA","NEW ZEALAND","USA","UAE","MAURITIUS");

        $.each(country_arr, function (i, item) {
            $('#country').append($('<option>', {
                value: i,
                text : item,
            }, '</option>' ));
        });

        // States
        var s_a = new Array();
        s_a[0]="Select State";
        s_a[1]="Select State|QUEENSLAND|VICTORIA";
        s_a[2]="Select State|ANDHRAPRADESH|KARNATAKA|TAMILNADU|DELHI|GOA|W-BENGAL|GUJARAT|MADHYAPRADESH|MAHARASHTRA|RAJASTHAN";
        s_a[3]="Select State|AUCKLAND";
        s_a[4]="Select State|NEWJERSEY|ILLINOIS";
        s_a[5]="Select State|DUBAI";
        s_a[6]="Select State|MAURITIUS";

        // Cities
        var c_a = new Array();
        c_a['QUEENSLAND']="BRISBANE";
        c_a['VICTORIA']="MELBOURNE";
        c_a['ANDHRAPRADESH']="HYDERABAD";
        c_a['KARNATAKA']="BANGLORE";
        c_a['TAMILNADU']="CHENNAI";
        c_a['DELHI']="DELHI";
        c_a['GOA']="GOA";
        c_a['W-BENGAL']="KOLKATA";
        c_a['GUJARAT']="AHMEDABAD1|AHMEDABAD2|AHMEDABAD3|BARODA|BHAVNAGAR|MEHSANA|RAJKOT|SURAT|UNA";
        c_a['MADHYAPRADESH']="INDORE";
        c_a['MAHARASHTRA']="MUMBAI|PUNE";
        c_a['RAJASTHAN']="ABU";
        c_a['AUCKLAND']="AUCKLAND";
        c_a['NEWJERSEY']="EDISON";
        c_a['ILLINOIS']="CHICAGO";
        c_a['MAURITIUS']="MAURITIUS";
        c_a['DUBAI']="DUBAI";


        $('#country').change(function(){
            var c = $(this).val();
            var state_arr = s_a[c].split("|");
            $('#state').empty();
            $('#city').empty();
            if(c==0){
                $('#state').append($('<option>', {
                    value: '0',
                    text: 'Select State',
                }, '</option>'));
            }else {
                $.each(state_arr, function (i, item_state) {
                    $('#state').append($('<option>', {
                        value: item_state,
                        text: item_state,
                    }, '</option>'));
                });
            }
            $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                value: '0',
                text: 'Select City',
            }, '</option>'));
        });

        $('#state').change(function(){
            var s = $(this).val();
            if(s=='Select State'){
                $('#city').empty();
                $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                    value: '0',
                    text: 'Select City',
                }, '</option>'));
            }
            var city_arr = c_a[s].split("|");
            $('#city').empty();

            $.each(city_arr, function (j, item_city) {
                $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                    value: item_city,
                    text: item_city,
                }, '</option>'));
            });


        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="country" id="country"></select> <br>
<select name="state" id="state"></select> <br>
<select name="city" id="city"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well there are plenty of sources online for SQL databases of such utility.
(I found that this one solved my problem: https://gist.github.com/ankitnetwork18/4509792)
The next steps are fairly straight-forward. Just load everything through an AJAX request.

Comment: That's just Indian cities - the question is asking for worldwide cities, and how to handle them in JavaScript.